# adding up specific mergefield values in word

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I have a table in a word document that has three colums and all fields are mailmerge fields from an external IT system.

There are three columns displaying the fields:
Charge Description
Charge Value (£)
Eiligible? (yes/no)

I am trying to create a field that adds up all eligibale charges so that only charge values that show a "yes" in the eligigble field are included. Does anyone know if this is possible? I have tried creating a formula but can't get it to work. Also, I would assume at some point an if statment is required so that it only includes the eligible charge.

Has anyone done anything similar before and if so, would they mind sharing how it was achieved?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do some things with expression fields (created in Word with CTRL-F9).  This will look like {} and you can insert the expression.  eg {{MERGFIELD charge} + {MERGEFIELD charge2}}.  Since however you want to check multiple values and then create an expression, its probably easier to use a macro.  The macro would contain your logic, then set the fields in the document accordingly.

Here are two external links since I can't reproduce a useful amount the content here because it's a verbose answer to a potentially deep question:

[Expression Fields](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/office-2010/word-2010-calculations-using-mail-merge-fields/)

[Merge fields](https://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks)

I hope that helps.